# msaccess 2010 memo field formatting, rich text specification

Tags: vba, ms-access, rtf, richtext

I am trying to format the font and size of some columns that have the `memo, rich text` datatype in Access 2010. Currently, users will oftentimes copy paste from different sources, but I want to be able to standardize the formatting without having to manually do it for each cell.

I was unable to find a way to do so via the Access user interface (it appears you can only change plain text formatting), so I attempted a VBA solution using regular expressions. However, it seems that the Microsoft's RTF specification isn't standard html. Some of the tags do seem to change when I pass it through my html parser, but others don't.

First, is there a way to directly view rich text with all of its meta tags? I have tried copying and pasting, but this copies the text as plaintext without tags.

Second, if I can't do this, is there some source that lists the Microsoft specification of rich text tags? I'm not looking to see what kinds of formatting are available, rather I want to know what tags (such as `<font face=...>`) correspond to font, size, etc.

Comment: For experimenting / debugging, you can add a second textbox to your form, with the same control source, but with TextFormat = Plain Text. This will show the HTML source.

Answer (score 2):

Up to Access 2003, you had a *RichText (RTF) OCX Control* producing true RTF formatted text.

From Access 2007 "rich text" means *HTML*, thus your control hos nothing to do with true RTF. "Rich text" only means that you can store text with HTML formatting.

However, only a *subset* of HTML is supported:
[Insert or add a rich text field](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Insert-or-add-a-rich-text-field-9f86237d-dbbc-4a85-b12c-9d8dca824630?CorrelationId=ac138a5a-af87-4fd3-b3f9-dfdc21b7ac05&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA010014097)

Comment: I tried to use normal HTML formatting, assuming that I can replace tags `<font face=...>` and <..size=..>. Some of these tags are replaced, but there are other areas where the font and size don't change. I've tested on regular strings with HTML tags and those work correctly, but when I pass it into the access function it doesn't. This makes me suspect that rich text isn't exactly HTML

Comment: It is, but it is limited. I've added a link to the answer.